# Unable to hit 0xff

Tags: c, jpeg

I am having a small challange(Can be found at the bottom of the page, title is CSI. https://x.cs50.net/2012/psets/4/pset4.html, was too long for me to paste.)
([And no, i am not trying to cheat, i already found a full code solution but i want mine to work..](https://github.com/CoreData/cs50/blob/master/pset4/jpg/recover.c))

The job is to pretty much sniff out JPG files in a .raw file(file uploaded)

I am using the below shown code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(void){
    FILE* fp = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("error!");
    }
    char foo[512];
    fread(foo,sizeof(foo),sizeof(foo[0]), fp);
    for(int j = 0; j < 20000; j++) {
        if (foo[0] == 0xff){
            printf("jackpot");
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            printf(" %d ", foo[0]);
            fread(foo,sizeof(foo),sizeof(foo[0]), fp);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, i dont know what the heck i am doing wrong. It is supposed to scream out and exit as soon as it hits a 0xff but instead it keeps going and going.. 
File can be found at https://mega.co.nz/#!tZcFWYIS!DmPAGT7FHLFgtW0SorWU-SE-gfJfR7MlbxdNucN1Biw
 if need be.

Update:
Thanks for everybody's help, i finally got the jackpot. Here is the end code i ended up with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;
int main(void){
    FILE* fp = fopen("card.raw", "rb");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("error!");
    }
    BYTE foo[512];    
    for (int j = 0;fread(foo,sizeof(foo),sizeof(foo[0]), fp) > 0; j++){
        if (foo[0] == 0xff){
            printf("jackpot, %d", j);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems that I see.

One is that you don't really check anything but the first byte of the blocks you read. The second is that you continue to read without regard of end-of-file or errors.

You should redesign to read in a loop (while checking for errors and end-of-file), and in that loop have another loop to find the byte-sequence you're looking for.

---

Something like this:

```
for (;;)
{
    size_t nread = fread(...);
    if (nread == 0)
    {
        /* Error or end-of-file */
        break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nread; i++)
    {
        /* Check for signature in `foo[i]` */
    }
}
```

---

If the signature is only found at the beginning of each 512-byte block, you don't need the second inner loop, and can simplify it considerably:

```
while (fread(...) > 0)
{
    /* Check for signature in `foo[0]` */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i dont know why but just switching to that had me hit jackpot!

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you are reading the file in `"r"` mode, which may translate newlines and mess up the block synchronization.

Try reading the file in `"rb"` mode (binary mode).